# Pagination doesn't work on second tab jPages plugin

Tags: jquery

On my second tab the pagination doesn't work.

```
Here's my jsfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/Rk8Pk/11/
```

Here I could reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone having same problem Please change in JPage.js line 58

```
/* only visible items! */
// this._items = this._container.children(":visible");
this._items = this._container.children();
```

It worked for me.